# Postgresql query question - same table works differently

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a question about Postgresql. The output is very unexpected and I could not understand how it works...

First, this is the table I am dealing with:
[image]

Here is the query codes:

first query code:

[image]

second query code:

[image]

As you see, the only difference is the first word in the fourth line; the first one has sections.instructor, and the second one has outside.instructor.

I understand the second output. The "where" command is redundant(true always), and all of the course numbers will be selected. The courseNumber that is equal to or more than all of the course numbers has to be the maximum courseNumber, which is 345 in this case.

The part that I am confused is why the first output does not show the same result with the second one. I think what "as" command does is to make Table "outside" and set it as eqault to Table "sections" (Table "outside" = Table "sections", therefore). How can the first result have different output from the second one while Table sections is quivalent to Table outside?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551  and sample data is also better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Note, `psql` is the Postgresql command line client not the database itself. I changed the question to indicate you are interested in Postgresql behavior not `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Sub query of first query is returning all the coursenumber for the instructor that's same as it's outer query.

But sub query of your second query is returning all the coursenumber from sections table.

That's why second query will only return the row with highest coursenumber.